# "OGR: not enough data error" when using st_transform in R

Tags: gdal, r, ogr, error

I'm trying to use `st_transform` (from the R package `sf`) on a `sf` object and am getting the following error when projecting from WGS 1984 to Albers Equal Area:

```
> sf_obj_prj <- sf_obj %>% 
   st_transform(crs = 
     "+proj=aea +lat_1=-5 +lat_2=-42 +lat_0=-32 +lon_0=-60 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=aust_SA +units=m +no_defs")
OGR: Not enough data 
Error in CPL_transform(x, crs$proj4string) : OGR error
In addition: Warning message:
In CPL_transform(x, crs$proj4string) :
GDAL Error 1: Length of input WKB is too small
```

I have checked that my map has a CRS:

```
> st_crs(sf_obj)
Coordinate Reference System:
EPSG: 4326 
proj4string: "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
```

I have also checked that all polygons are valid:

```
> which(!is_true(st_is_valid(sf_obj)))
integer(0)
```

(`is_true` is my user-defined function that returns TRUE if true and FALSE if NA/false)

I've tried searching but could not find anything about this error.

**EDIT 1:**
It seems that this is arising after using `rbind` to bind two objects.

Here is the `st_bbox` on the two objects:

```
> st_bbox(sf1)
      xmin       ymin       xmax       ymax 
-73.991244 -11.145219 -66.619911  -7.111824 
> st_bbox(sf2)
     xmin      ymin      xmax      ymax 
-62.68262  80.03352 -57.99074  82.14633
```

`st_transform` works on the objects separately, but not when I use `rbind`:

```
> x = st_transform(sf1, crs = prj_alber)
> y = st_transform(sf2, crs = prj_alber)
> z = st_transform(rbind(sf1, sf2), crs = prj_alber)
OGR: Not enough data 
Error in CPL_transform(x, crs$proj4string) : OGR error
In addition: Warning message:
In CPL_transform(x, crs$proj4string) :
  GDAL Error 1: Length of input WKB is too small
```

**EDIT 2:** 
Here is code to reproduce the error (note: requires downloading data from the Brazilian statistics office)

```
download.file(
  "http://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_de_setores_censitarios__divisoes_intramunicipais/censo_2000/setor_rural/projecao_geografica/censo_2000/e1000_generico_dxf/uf/ac.zip",
  paste0(directory, "sf1.zip"))
unzip(paste0(directory, "sf1.zip"), exdir = paste0(directory, "sf1"))

download.file(
  "http://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_de_setores_censitarios__divisoes_intramunicipais/censo_2000/setor_urbano/ac/1200203/1200203.zip",
  paste0(directory, "sf2.zip"))
unzip(paste0(directory, "sf2.zip"), exdir = paste0(directory, "sf2"))


sf1 <- st_read(paste0(directory, "sf1/AC/12SE1000G.dxf"))
# (original crs undefined)
st_crs(sf1) <- "+init=epsg:5527"
sf1 <- st_transform(sf1, crs = "+init=epsg:4326")
sf1 <- sf1 %>% dplyr::select(ID = Text)

sf2 <- st_read(paste0(directory, "sf2/1200203.SHP"))
# (original crs was defined for northern hemisphere, this is the epsg code for southern hemisphere)
st_crs(sf2) <- "+init=epsg:32718"
sf2 <- sf2 %>% st_transform(sf2, crs = "+init=epsg:4326")
# (some polygons were invalid so fixing them here)
invalid = which(!is_true(st_is_valid(sf2)))
sf2[invalid, ] = st_make_valid(sf2[invalid,])
sf2 <- sf2 %>% dplyr::select(ID = ID_)

> x = st_transform(sf1, crs = prj_alber)
> y = st_transform(sf2, crs = prj_alber)
> z = st_transform(rbind(sf1, sf2), crs = prj_alber)
OGR: Not enough data 
Error in CPL_transform(x, crs$proj4string) : OGR error
In addition: Warning message:
In CPL_transform(x, crs$proj4string) :
  GDAL Error 1: Length of input WKB is too small
```

But as per Spacedman's solution below, removing the extra dimension fixes the issue:

```
z <- st_transform(st_zm(rbind(sf1, sf2)), crs = prj_alber)
```

Comment: Works for me for a test epsg 4326 dataset `nc` derived from running `example(st_read)`. Must be something in your data. Are the source coordinates in the right range? What's `st_bbox` telling you? Does it work on a subset of features in your source data?

Comment: Thanks for the questions - I've updated the question to elaborate more about the data I'm working with

Comment: Very very weird. Any chance you can share your data? Its not a general problem since I just rbinded two halves of an sf data frame and it works fine. Does it fail with other projections (try "+init=epsg:3857")? Can you show `summary()` of your objects if you cant share them

Comment: I can share - it's publicly available data from the Brazilian government.  I'm not sure how to do it though, how would you suggest I share?

Comment: Sorry - I am being silly.  Here are the links to the datasets.  This is sf1: http://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_de_setores_censitarios__divisoes_intramunicipais/censo_2000/setor_rural/projecao_geografica/censo_2000/e1000_generico_dxf/uf/ and this is sf2: http://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_de_setores_censitarios__divisoes_intramunicipais/censo_2000/setor_urbano/ac/1200203/

Comment: That first link is a folder full of zip files - I downloaded one and it extracted to a bunch of DXF files.... What should I be using?

Comment: Apologies - the "ac.zip" folder (AC is the state in the second link).  I've just discovered one issue in the second link, which is that the crs is incorrect (the ESPG codes are for UTM northern hemisphere, but should be southern hemisphere).  It doesn't solve the error, however.  For the first link, you need to set the crs (which corresponds to EPSG 4326)

Comment: And for the first link, you should be using "12SE1000G.dxf"

Comment: print the objects and place the output in the q please, or reprex code to get data that causes the problem

Comment: But, are any of the entries in `st_is_valid(sf_obj)` NA perchance? `unique(st_is_valid(sf_obj))` to let us know. This bites in plotting, with degenerate polygons where "valid" is NA, not FALSE.

Comment: `12SE1000G.dxf` and `1200203.SHP` have different column structures so an `rbind` fails before it gets a chance to join them. Please edit your question to show how you go from a DXF and a shapefile to an error with `rbind`.

Comment: Apologies for all the confusion.  Spacedman's solution works, but I've edited the question to reproduce the error for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get this error if I mix objects with different dimensions. Here's a reproducible example:

First make a data frame with two points:

```
d = st_as_sf(data.frame(x=1:2,y=1:2,z=c("A","B")), coords=1:2)
```

Next make two points with different dimensionalities:

```
p1 = st_point(c(1,1,2,3), dim="XYZM")
p2 = st_point(c(1,2), dim="XY")
```

Replace the points in the data frame (at which point I think there's probably an easier way to do this by nm):

```
d$geometry[1] = p1
d$geometry[2] = p2
```

Give the thing a CRS - lat-long is valid:

```
st_crs(d)=4326
```

And now transform to oooh, Google Web Mercator:

```
st_transform(d,3857)
# OGR: Not enough data 
# Error in CPL_transform(x, crs$proj4string) : OGR error
```

To fix, wrap the object in `st_zm` which removes any Zs or Ms and returns a purely XY object:

```
> st_transform(st_zm(d),3857)
Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 111319.5 ymin: 111325.1 xmax: 111319.5 ymax: 222684.2
epsg (SRID):    3857
proj4string:    +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs
  z                  geometry
1 A POINT (111319.5 111325.1)
2 B POINT (111319.5 222684.2)
```

If you need the Zs and the Ms then you'll have to take them from the original objects and add them back. Remembering that some of the rows didn't have them in the first place....